# Symfony 3 micro kernel catch not allowed method exception

Tags: php, symfony

I want to catch method not allowed exception but i don't know where place `try` and `catch` block.

index.php

```
<?php

...

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        return [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle()
        ];
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $c->loadFromExtension('framework', [
            'secret' => 'S0ME_SECRET'
        ]);
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $routes->add('/test', 'kernel:indexAction', 'test')
            ->setMethods('POST');
    }

    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {

        //return empty json with 200 http cocde
        return new JsonResponse();
    }

}

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

When i use GET method to test route i get fatal error:

`Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException'`

but i want to response empty json with 405 http code. This is one file symfony app and I wouldn't change that. I will be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Did you try in in prod with debug off? In dev mode and debug on you always get those nice exception pages.

Comment: You're right Thanks!